# screenOrientation portrait not always working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm making activity which should always remain in one orientation on all devices, preferably portrait.

here is my activity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.Settings"
    android:label="@string/settings_activity_title"
    android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It works on phone devices but when I tested on virtual tablet it didn't.
I test on **Nexus 9** in Android Studio and made my own device with dimensions 2500x2500, screen size 9in.

In such cases, screen will still rotate.

I have also tried setting orientation programmatically inside `onCreate` method but it didn't help.
I tried to find any information regarding this problem but couldn't.

My question is if this is related to android studio emulator, or this can happen on physical device

Comment: What do you consider the "portrait" orientation on a device with screen 2500x2500 ?

Comment: @Jean I would consider any one side being it, and another landscape. Important question is what android considers "portrait"

Comment: Android has an orientation it will call portrait and one it will call landscape. If you start the app while in orientation landscape, with your code it will rotate to portrait first (this will be true no matter the device).
If you want to take the original orientation your app is launched in but never change from it, well first consider why you wouldn't want to rotate if you support both orientations. But then you can probably achieve this by setting android:configChanges="orientation" in your activity tag, then overriding onConfigurationChanged in your activity to do what you need.

Comment: yes, that is exactly how I view it. but it doesn't work. you can test it yourself, when setting orientation portrait, it should be locked in one orientation and prevent rotation of the screen right? but it doesn't